# How to store comma seperated string into a table

Tags: java

im trying to insert comma separated string into a table

here is my Soultion:

```
String str = "83.320869,17.735924,83.322868,17.737820,83.323715,17.738564";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split(",")); // split-ing the string`
ArrayList<Double> ala = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> alo = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (String i : list) {

            double d = Double.parseDouble(i);

            if (d > 82 & d < 84) {

                ala.add(d);

            } else {
                alo.add(d);
            }

        }
        for(int in =0 ; in<=2; in++){
            String sql2 = "insert into routes values(" + ala.get(in) + "," + alo.get(in)+ ")";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);
        }
```

finally got the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there are the right number of comma separated items in the list, this doesn't make any assumption based on the lat/long pair values. I'd be tempted to include a check to make sure you don't end up with an odd longitude at the end of the list though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "83.320869,17.735924,83.322868,17.737820,83.323715,17.738564";
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split(",")); // split-ing the string
    Iterator<String> i = list.iterator();
    double lat = 0, lon = 0;
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        lat = Double.parseDouble(i.next());
        lon = Double.parseDouble(i.next());
        System.out.println("lat=" + lat + ", long=" + lon);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is due to improper split to identify positions of lat longs from the array.

Change your code to use multiple split placeholders like a `';'` and `','`.

**Example**:

```
// ; is to separate a pair of lat-longs
String str = "83.320869,17.735924;83.322868,17.737820;83.323715,17.738564";

List<String> latLongsList = Arrays.asList( str.split( ";" ) ); // split-ing the string

String sql2 = "insert into routes values( ?, ? )";

// use prepared statement to bind values with query
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement( sql2 );

for ( String latLongTogether : latLongsList ) {
    // comma is to separate lat and long value
    String lat_long[] = latLongTogether.split( "," );
    double lat = Double.parseDouble( lat_long[ 0 ] );
    double lon = Double.parseDouble( lat_long[ 1 ] );

    if ( ( lat > 82 && lat < 84 ) && ( lon > 16 && lon < 18 ) ) {
        pst.setDouble( 1, lat );
        pst.setDouble( 2, lon );

        pst.executeUpdate();
        pst.clearParameters();
    } // if
 }  // for
```

Comment: why use multiple split placeholders like a `;` and `,` when split by `,` is desired

Comment: It was required, because first 2 numbers in the `str` are are a single set of lat-long and so on. For ease in understanding, I demonstrated with 2 split placeholders. With that both can be read at once and send to query. Otherwise, for loop needs a counter to wait until read next value as lot value.

Comment: k now i got the intention and the code doesn't match (as asked in question). lat = lattitude , lon= longitude.

Comment: Which part do you think is not correct. Explain in detail.

Comment: i understood all and ur answer is correct . Initially i cudn't figure out questioners intention . i never thought he wanted a pair of values. well now i cudn't cancel downvote unless answer is edited

Comment: @KNU: Many a times, mostly on SO, we give example code snippets and suggestions only, thinking that OP is capable of understanding an analysis and would implement it with changes if required. And hence, I feel, should not downvote unless until a suggestion is clarified to be correct.